# How does the ternary operator work in this recursive code?

Tags: java

In the last call on the stack, num will equal 0, so why doesn't the code return 0?

```
public static int Add(int num) {
    return(num == 0 ? 0 : num + Add(num - 1));
}

    int num = 7;
```

Comment: Because it returns `num + Add(num - 1)` when it's not zero.

Comment: Best approach: write it out on paper

Comment: It will return 28, because num equals 7 in the beginning, not zero. So the 
 sequence is `7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 28`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your confusion lies in the fact that the last return statement does not directly return `0` to the `main()`. Instead the `return` statement will return to the caller of the function. In this case the caller will be itself. Here's a visualization with the extremely simple case of passing `1` to `Add()`:

```
//num == 1
//Since num != 0, we will return num + Add(num - 1)
//But the compiler doesn't know what Arr(num -1) is
return num + ______;
```

In the blank space is where the result of `Add(num -1)` will go. The current call to `Add()` is pushed onto the stack and a new call to `Add(num -1)` is called:

```
public static int Add(int num) {
    return(num == 0 ? 0 : num + Add(num - 1));
}
```

Here `num == 0` so the method returns `0`. *But not to the main*. It returns it to the previous call to `Add()`, right where the theoretical blank is. So:

```
return num + ______;
```

Becomes

```
return num + 0;
```

Since this is the last call on the stack, this returns to the main, with a result of `1`, which is correct for the simply case of calling `Add(1)`